# Implementation of user defined array on stack and/or heap in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, stack, heap-memory

I am trying to understand the difference between the **stack** and the **heap** whilst learning programming in C.
To do this, I have attempted to implement the binary search. I want to obtain the input data set of the binary search from the user. In order to do this, I want that the user be able to define the size of the data set (array in this case). Once I obtain the size of the array, I initialise the array and then ask the user to fill it up with values.

My (potentially wrong) understanding of the stack is, that the array can be initialised on the stack if its size is known at compile time. So, I tried the following to implement the user input on the stack (and it 'works'):

```c
void getUserInput(int sizeArray, int inputArray[], int userIn[]){
    /* get input data set and the element to be searched for from user */

    printf("Enter data elements seperated by a comma, e.g. 1,2,3. Press Enter at the end. Do not enter more than %d numbers: \n", sizeArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++){
        scanf("%d, ", &inputArray[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the number to be searched for: \n");
    scanf("%d", &userIn[1]);

    printf("\nFor iterative implementation, enter 0. For recursive implementation, enter 1 :\n");
    scanf("%d", &userIn[0]);
}

int main(int arg, char **argv){
   int sizeArray;
   int userIn[2];                                                  // userIn[1]: element to be searched for; userIn[0]: iterative or recursive implementations
   printf("Enter size of input array: \n");
   scanf("%d", &sizeArray);
        
   int inputArray[sizeArray];
        
   getUserInput(sizeArray, inputArray, userIn);

// more code ...

}
```

For an implementation on the heap, I attempted to use dynamic memory allocation (it also 'works'):

```c
int main(int arg, char **argv) {
    int sizeArray;
    int userIn[2];                                                  // userIn[1]: element to be searched for; userIn[0]: iterative or recursive implementations
    printf("Enter size of input array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeArray);

    int *inputArray;

    inputArray = (int*) malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
    if(inputArray == NULL) {
        printf("\n\nError! Memory not allocated, enter size of array again:\n");
        scanf("%d", &sizeArray);
        inputArray = (int*) malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
    }
    getUserInput(sizeArray, inputArray, userIn);

// more code...
    free(inputArray)                                               // free memory allocated by malloc on the heap
}
```

Now, I wanted to combine both approaches into one file, so I created a switch to switch between the stack and heap implementations, as follows:

```c
int main(int arg, char **argv) {
    /* Obtain input */
    int stackHeap;                                                      // 0 = implementation on stack; 1 = implementation on heap
    printf("Implementation on stack or heap? Enter 0 for stack, 1 for heap: \n");
    scanf("%d", &stackHeap);

    int sizeArray;
    int userIn[2];                                                  // userIn[1]: element to be searched for; userIn[0]: iterative or recursive implementations
    printf("Enter size of input array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeArray);
    int *inputArray;

    if (stackHeap == 0) {
        inputArray =  &inputArray[sizeArray];    
        printf("input array = %p\n", inputArray);
    } else {
        inputArray = (int*) malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
        printf("input array = %p\n", inputArray);
        if(inputArray == NULL) {
            printf("\n\nError! Memory not allocated, enter size of array again:\n");
            scanf("%d", &sizeArray);
            inputArray = (int*) malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
        }
    }

    getUserInput(sizeArray, inputArray, userIn);
// more code...
}
```

Currently the stack approach doesn't work. Instead of inputArray = &inputArray[sizeArray], I tried initialising the inputArray within the if statement. This is however not allowed, since it is then only valid within the scope of the if statement. I think I am getting confused as how to use the pointer *inputArray to initialise the array on the stack.

I have been reading about pointers and arrays in C, which is why I thought implementing this would be fun. I would very much appreciate any feedback you have (gladly also any fundamental errors I have made - I am quite new to this topic).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to understand the difference between the stack and the heap and whilst learning programming in C.

That was your first mistake.  Stack and heap are not C-language concepts, and the C language does not depend on any such distinctions between areas of memory.  With that said, many C implementations effectively do rely on these, so understanding something about them may prove worthwhile.  As far as learning the C language goes, however, it would be better to focus on the relevant native C concepts.

In this particular area, those would be the connected concepts of objects' *lifetime* and *storage duration*.  An object's lifetime is the portion of the program's execution during which that object exists and retains its last-stored value, which is a function of its storage duration and, for some objects, the timing of their creation.  Storage duration is defined by the location of an object's definition, if any, and of the type qualifiers applying to it.

Objects declared without the `static` qualifier inside a code block have "automatic" storage duration and live from entry into the block to termination of the block's execution.  On stack-based machines, storage for such objects is typically allocated on the stack.  The other storage durations are "static", "allocated", and "thread", and on stack-based machines, storage for objects with these durations typically is implemented outside the stack, which some would describe as on the heap.

> My (potentially wrong) understanding of the stack is, that the array can be initialised on the stack if its size is known at compile time.

That's somewhat imprecise.

On one hand, if the wanted size is known at compile time then you can certainly write a valid declaration for an automatic-duration array with that size.  However, that does not guarantee that the program can actually obtain the wanted space at run time.  This is an especial problem when objects with very large storage size are declared: when program execution reaches the point where such an object must be allocated, stack-oriented C implementations may not have enough stack space available.  This is the "stack overflow" for which this site is named.

On the other hand, all conforming C99 implementations and most C11 and C17 implementations support variable-length arrays, which have size determined at run time and can be the types of automatic objects.  This is, in fact, what you have employed for variable `inputArray` in your first example.  That code is valid.  Some implementations may provide other mechanisms for allocating variable-length data as automatic storage, too.  See [alloca()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), for example.

> For an implementation on the heap, I attempted to use dynamic memory allocation

This gets you an object with "allocated" storage duration.  On implementations that you can characterize as maintaining a stack / heap distinction, storage for such objects is indeed ordinarily on the heap.

> Now, I wanted to combine both approaches into one file, so I created a switch to switch between the stack and heap implementations

That's doable, but not the way you're trying to do it.  Having declared ...

> ```
>     int *inputArray;
> ```

... you need to assign that pointer to point to something before you can access its elements.  You do that in the one case by allocating memory with `malloc`, but in the other case, this ...

> ```
>         inputArray =  &inputArray[sizeArray];
> ```

... does not do at all what you want.  Appearing as it does in an expression rather than a declaration, that `inputArray[sizeArray]` does not cause any memory to be allocated.  Instead, it attempts to access an `int` at index `sizeArray` in the object to which `inputArray` points.  Since `inputArray` has not, at that point, been assigned a value, that produces undefined behavior.  Thus, indeed,

> Currently the stack approach doesn't work.

And you are also right that

> initialising the inputArray within the
> if statement [is] not allowed, since it is then only valid
> within the scope of the if statement.

So when you say,

> I think I am getting confused as
> how to use the pointer *inputArray to initialise the array on the
> stack.

, I am inclined to agree.  In fact, I think you are missing a key point, which is that you can't in either case use the pointer to initialize an array, nor really anything like that.  Rather, you must allocate the array and, more or less separately, assign the pointer to point to it.

You clearly know how to do that with `malloc`, though I suppose you weren't thinking about that in those terms.  The way you are doing it works because the object allocated via `malloc` has "allocated" storage duration, meaning that its lifetime lasts until it is deallocated.  To do similar with an automatic object, you need one that has sufficient lifetime for your purpose, which in this case means that it must be declared directly within the body of `main()`, not in any nested block.  You can achieve that like this:

```
    int sizeArray;
    int sizeAutomatic = 1;

    printf("Enter size of input array: \n");
    scanf("%d", &sizeArray);

    if (stackHeap == 0) {
        sizeAutomatic = sizeArray;
    }

    int automaticArray[sizeAutomatic];
    int *inputArray;

    if (stackHeap == 0) {
        inputArray = automaticArray;
        // or, equivalently: inputArray = &automaticArray[0];
    } else {
        inputArray = malloc(sizeArray * sizeof(int));
        if(inputArray == NULL) {
            /// handle allocation error ...
        }
    }

    printf("input array = %p\n", (void *)inputArray);
```

In the event that the user elects the automatic allocation option, `inputArray` will point to the first element of `automaticArray`, effectively making the two aliases for each other.  In the other case, `inputArray` will point to an allocated object.  The `automaticArray` object will still exist in the latter case, but it will have length 1 and be unused.  This one-`int` overhead is part of the price you pay for allowing the user to decide which allocation approach to use.

Comment: Wow. First of all, thank you very much for such a detailed explanation. I think you've clarified a few concepts for me via this post.  
I'll try to re-iterate my understanding of your post:  
- Through this implementation, fundamentally the same idea has been implemented in both approaches -> we are pointing the pointer to an array that has been allocated (already). You are right, this was the piece I was finding difficult to grasp. [1/2]

Comment: - I understand why you defined int `sizeAutomatic = 1`(for the case of the heap, the automaticArray is initialised to an array of length 1). I tried implementing it by just declaring `int sizeAutomatic;` Does this mean during runtime, if I select the heap method, I am declaring the automaticArray (needlessly) of a random number length? [2/2]

Comment: One more question regarding _object lifetime_ and _storage duration_. If I understand correctly, both concepts put together in a sense describe the scope of a variable? Because the scope of a variable tells me where the variable is valid (and accessible) as well as what it's value is. Or am I mixing two different things together?

Comment: @sar (1/2): yes. (2/2): if you modify the code I presented by removing the initializer for `sizeAutomatic`, then you reap undefined behavior in the dynamic allocation case when execution reaches the declaration of `automaticArray`.  You use an assignment in place of an initializer, but you must attempt to use the value of an object before that object's value has been set.

Comment: @sar (3/2): You are mixing two things.  Scope is a property of identifiers, not of objects.  The lifetime of an object with automatic storage duration is closely related to the scope of its identifier, but there is no association between identifier scope and lifetime for objects having other storage durations.  Objects with allocated duration don't even have identifiers.  Additionally, identifier scope and storage duration are both affected by the location of declarations, but it is best to look at declaration placement as a separate consideration for each of those.

Answer (score 0):

Your programs using just stack allocation or just heap allocation are both fine.  The only potential problem you have with the stack allocation is that if the array is too big (i.e. a few MB) it can overflow the stack, while the heap has a *much* higher limit.

The problem with the combined program is that this doesn't make sense:

```
inputArray =  &inputArray[sizeArray];
```

Using the array index operator actually involves dereferencing a pointer, and at this point `inputArray` doesn't point anywhere.

You need to pick one or the other, either an array or a pointer that points to the start of a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: You need to find the way how to do not define automatic storage array if heap type is selected. But it has to be defined in both cases

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. You are correct, I was getting confused with the pointer *inputArray. As @johnbollinger pointed out, I have to point the pointer at something, so I have gone with their implementation of creating a temporary array within the scope of the function. I then point to this array using the inputArray pointer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef enum
{
    STACK,
    HEAP,
}type;

size_t getSize(void)  // implement user input
{
    return 100;
}

type getType(void)   // implement user input
{
    return HEAP;
}

int main(void)
{
    size_t stackSize = 0;
    size_t size;
    type tp;
    int *inputArray;

    size = getSize();
    tp = getType();

    if(tp == STACK) stackSize = size;

    int array[stackSize];

    if(tp == STACK)
        inputArray = array;
    else
        inputArray = malloc(size * sizeof(*inputArray));

    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I'm sorry, but I'm finding it difficult to understand your code. I'm not very confident with regard to typedef and enums, with my understanding regarding the concepts being almost negligible. I'll try to study the concepts further and will then come back to your code!

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: don't use VLAs unless you need their special semantics.  They're tricky and somewhat error prone; using the heap is generally easier and safer.

The basic problem that you're running into is that defining a VLA is a *declaration*, so there's no way to conditionally create one that lives on after the conditional block.  That's pretty much by design -- the block serves to limit the lifetime so it can be freed automatcially.

So your choices are to to create one unconditionally (and just not use it if `stackHeap` is true) or move all your ...more code... into the conditional block.  The latter would be easiest to do by putting it all in a function (eg `processArray(int sizeArray, int inputArray[],`... much like your `getUserInput` function).  Then you just need two calls to the function in the if and else cases.

Comment: It is not needed at all. See my answer. As a maximum you will waste `sizeof(int)` id implementation does not support zero-sized arrays.

Comment: `They're tricky and somewhat error prone; using the heap is generally easier and safer.` Both are same error prone and same unsafe.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. VLAs are variable-length arrays? I'm confused - you mention not to use VLAs, but then say using the heap is easier and safer. My inputArray created using malloc is also creating a variable length array - so why would it be safer/error prone?

Also, regarding your recommendation in the last paragraph. That's exactly how I had implemented the two separate solutions until now. But through that I have a lot of 'copied' code, which I wanted to remove, hence my attempt at merging both solutions.